# What is best lower bound for comparison sort?

Tags: reference-request, sorting, worst-case

Sorting $n$ numbers requires $\lceil \log_2(n!)\rceil$ comparisons and this is asymptotically optimal, but there is an $O(n)$ error term.

> What is the best known lower bound for large $n$?

I couldn't even find $\lceil \log_2(n!)\rceil+1$ proved anywhere, but I suspect even $\lceil \log_2(n!)\rceil+\omega(1)$ might be known.
Some useful links: [OEIS A036604](https://oeis.org/A036604) of known exact values, [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list), and Knuth: TAOCP Vol. 3 section 5.3.

Comment: It appears the error term can be reduced to $o(n)$, see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41493/sorting-with-an-average-of-mathrmlgnon-comparisons

Comment: I didn't realize this was an open problem, nice!

Comment: Are you asking about worst-case or average-case?

Comment: Worst case is enough for me.

Comment: @domotorp Please @ me so I receive the notification. Also, just to emphasize it, we have equality for $n=21$, so a lower bound of $\lceil \log_2(n!)\rceil + 1$ can only hold for $n > 21$.

Comment: @domotorp The wikipedia page you linked to.